# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/google/gson/Gson

Tags: java, eclipse, gson

I don't know if someone can help me but it turns out that I have a problem with the following code:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Juego {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ejemplo.json"));
            String linea ="";
            while ( (linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                json += linea;
            }
        br.close();
        //
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Juego.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    System.out.println(json);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Lector p = gson.fromJson(json, Lector.class);
    System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

But when compiling I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    at Juego.main(Juego.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't know how to fix it

I have already tried many things, including inserting the library in various ways (directly, as a user library), changing the location of the .jar in case the compiler did not have access to the directory where it was but I cannot find any solution

Comment: It appears that GSON JAR file is not included in the classpath in the run configuration in Eclipse. Or are you using Maven or Gradle to run your code?

Comment: how could i do it

Comment: Search for **eclipse run configuration**.